# Resizing rectangle when resizing main window while Rectangle's size is changed in python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

What I try is part of a larger App but I posted here the minimum to understand my problem:

I want to change the size of a rectangle, and that this size depends on the root.height .

**3 cases:**

1) When I create a rectangle with "root.height/4" as a height, the size varies as I resize the root window. *So far no problem*

2) When I tried to assign "root.height/4" to an attribut and call this attribut when setting the size of my rectangle I get the following error: 
"TypeError: a float is required".

*Python file:*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color


class BriqueApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return BriqueGUI()


class BriqueGUI(Widget):
    pass

BriqueApp().run()
```

*Kv file:*

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<BriqueGUI>:
    h: root.height/4
    color: (1,0,0,1)

    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgba: root.color
        Rectangle:
            size: (200, self.h)
            pos: (0,0)
```

[image: float error]

3) When I tried to reassign a value depending on, for example "root.height/2", when an event is call (here on_touch_down) : The size of my Rectangle changes but when I resize my windows my rectangle doesn't resize with it.
You can see the problem here loading the file, clicking in the main window, and changing its size.

*Python file:*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color


class BriqueApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return BriqueGUI()


class BriqueGUI(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.h = self.height/2

BriqueApp().run()
```

*Kv file:*

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<BriqueGUI>:
    h: 20
    color: (1,0,0,1)

    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgba: root.color
        Rectangle:
            size: (200, self.h)
            pos: (0,0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2) You have to create property in your Python code as well:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string(""" 
<BriqueGUI>:
    h: root.height/4
    color: (1,0,0,1)

    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgba: root.color
        Rectangle:
            size: (200, self.h)
            pos: (0,0)
""")

class BriqueApp(App):  
    def build(self):
        return BriqueGUI()


class BriqueGUI(Widget):
    h = NumericProperty(0.0)

BriqueApp().run()
```

3) You're only assigning once a value to your `h` property. What you need is `bind` method that allows you to associate a callback that will be called any time the property changes:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string(""" 
<BriqueGUI>:
    h: 20
    color: (1,0,0,1)

    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgba: root.color
        Rectangle:
            size: (200, self.h)
            pos: (0,0)
""")

class BriqueApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return BriqueGUI()


class BriqueGUI(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.h = self.height/2
        self.bind(height=self.set_h)

    def set_h(self, instance, value):
        self.h = value/2

BriqueApp().run()
```

Comment: 2) That's exactly what I was looking for ! I knew about NumericProperty but I couldn't figure out how to use them so thanks !  
3) I didn't know that we can directly bind "height", that a good way to do it so thanks. But isn't there an other way, something which makes kivy understand that it's not a value but a NumericProperty that we assign tu the attribut and which will make kivy automatically update the size for us ?

Comment: @Lulupointu that's what you are doing with the `bind` - otherwise they are just two unrelated variables/properties. [Kivy Properties](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html) says it's the "Observer Pattern" - ```You can specify what should happen when a property’s value changes. You can bind your own function as a callback to changes of a Property. ``` And as a minor comment, you don't need an *explicit* bind, it's possible to define a function ```def on_height(self, instance, value): self.h = value/2```. Properties are auto-bound to `on_X` as a default Observer.